# hg log - how to display a date range of revisions in reverse order?

Tags: bash, mercurial, revision, hg-log

In bash, I am using a date range to restrict the number of revisions showed as follows:

```
hg log -d "yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd"
```

I would like to output to display the most recent revision at the bottom. Currently, it starts with the most recent at the top & works it's way down.

Thanks in advance!

---

I am trying to implement the `hg log -r "(date("$startdate to $enddate"))"` solution into a bash script as per below:

```
read -p "Specify start of date range(yyyy-mm-dd): " startdate
read -p "Specify end of date range(yyyy-mm-dd): " enddate
hg log -r '(date("$startdate to $enddate"))'
```

However, the variables are no longer recognised. I have tried using double quotes & also quoting the variables themselves but no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) instead:

```
hg log -r 'reverse(date("yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd"))'
```

Comment: Just a follow on question. I am trying to implement the above into a bash script as per the below:
read -p "Specify start of date range(yyyy-mm-dd): " startdate
read -p "Specify end of date range(yyyy-mm-dd): " enddate
hg log -r '(date("$startdate to $enddate"))' 

However, the variables are no longer accepted in this format. I have tried with double quotes and quoting the variables to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace outer single quotes with double and escape the inner quotes with a backslash

Comment: Works for me. Example: hg log -r "reverse(date(\"2020-12-31 to 2021-01-01\"))"